# Read Epochdate and return result in different formats

Tags: sql, epoch

I am reading an epoch date (Field name = "LINKED") using this statement:

```
CAST(DATE '1970-01-01' + (LINKED / 86400000) AS TIMESTAMP(0)) 
  + ((LINKED MOD 86400) * INTERVAL '00:00:01' HOUR TO SECOND) as a.
```

It returns the field as `2018/07/01 01:22:34`.

I would like to format that result to `201807`, but I don't know how to do that.

Anyone that can assist please? Thank you!

Comment: Please tag the question with database that you are using

Comment: how do I tag the question? Sorry - I am new to the forum